# Joomla 3 problems using Akeeba Release system with zip

Tags: zip, joomla3.0

I'm trying to use the Joomla ARS.  I've set it up and it seems to work for everything except the download of zip files.

I've set it up so that you can see the file in the front end but when you click on it a:

The requested document was not found on this server

error is thrown.

I've tried directly linking the file and it downloads fine.  I've also set up an article to check that it'll download and again it works fine.  So I don't think there are any permission issues since the zip file can be downloaded just not by using ARS.

Finally I've also tried different file types in ARS and if I swap the zip file for an xml file or a pdf file they both download fine.

Any ideas about how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :)

The site had add a suffix to url switched on which was stopping it getting the correct route.  Changed that and it worked as expected.